# Custom GridViewItem Selection - Windows Store App C#/XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm trying to change the style of selecting items in a gridview. Below the code I'm using in StandardStyles.xaml:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Opacity="0.25" Color="Blue"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Opacity="0.7" Color="Blue"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Blue"/>
```

But I need what the border with the selected icon stay with some style and the background transparent, like this:

[Selected Image Style](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/sdffsdfd.png/)

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use a rectangle in `StandardStyles.xaml` beneath each GridViewItem the custom selection works.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplete">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="1"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to set the style of a selected item. It will set the border color, the text color and the check icon color.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#323232"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush" Color="White"></SolidColorBrush>
```

Regards.

Comment: I wanted that color doesn't fill all, only the border of the selection.